# first object key value compare with the another object key?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native, object

I have two data one is array of objects and second is a **mapping object**. so i am trying  to implement the logic that , my first object and their **subarr** objects of the array has key value `id:1` then, match that 1 is available as a key in the anther mapping object. so how can i solve it?

data 1(array of object)

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Dashboard",
    "route": "Dashboard",
    "routeid": 1,
    "key": "dashboard",
    "icon": "home",
    "subarr": []
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "title": "Pages",
    "route": "Pages",
    "routeid": 2,
    "key": "pages",
    "icon": "diamond",
    "subarr": [
      {
        "id": 3,
        "title": "Tabs",
        "route": "Tabs",
        "key": "tab",
        "routeid": 3,
        "icon": "grid"
      },
      {
        "id": 4,
        "route": "Test",
        "key": "test",
        "icon": "adn",
        "routeid": 4,
        "title": "Test"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "title": "Components",
    "key": "Components",
    "route": "component",
    "routeid": 5,
    "icon": "notebook",
    "subarr": [
      {
        "id": 6,
        "route": "Card",
        "key": "card",
        "icon": "i-card",
        "routeid": 6,
        "title": "Card"
      },
      {
        "id": 7,
        "title": "Button",
        "route": "Button",
        "routeid": 7,
        "key": "button",
        "icon": "control-play"
      },
      {
        "id": 8,
        "title": "Table",
        "route": "Table",
        "key": "table",
        "routeid": 8,
        "icon": "list"
      },
      {
        "id": 9,
        "title": "Charts",
        "route": "Chart",
        "routeid": 9,
        "key": "chart",
        "icon": "chart"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 10,
    "title": "notifications",
    "route": "User",
    "key": "user",
    "routeid": 10,
    "icon": "bell",
    "subarr": []
  },
  {
    "id": 11,
    "title": "User profile",
    "route": "Profile",
    "routeid": 11,
    "key": "profile",
    "icon": "user",
    "subarr": []
  },
  {
    "id": 12,
    "title": "Carousel",
    "route": "Carousel",
    "key": "carousel",
    "routeid": 12,
    "icon": "layers",
    "subarr": []
  }
]
```

mapping object:

```
{
  "1": "dashboard",
  "2": "pages",
  "3": "tab",
  "4": "test",
  "6": "card",
  "7": "button",
  "8": "table",
  "9": "chart",
  "10": "user",
  "11": "profile",
  "12": "carousel"
}
```

Comment: what would be your final outcome? just checking if the key value of `1` exists in mapping object or not?

Comment: @alisasani thanks for replay, I just want to check that the value 1 is exist as key in the mapping object or not?

Comment: did you find my answer helpful?

Answer (score 1):

[sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-kirch-1o95l?file=/src/App.js)

```
let exists = [];

data1.map((el, id) => {
      if (Object.keys(mapping).includes(el.id.toString()))
        exists = [...exists, { id: el.id, exists: true }];
      else exists = [...exists, { id: el.id, exists: false }];
      el.subarr.map((l, i) => {
        if (Object.keys(mapping).includes(l.id.toString()))
          exists = [...exists, { id: l.id, exists: true }];
          else exists = [...exists, { id: l.id, exists: false }];
      });
    });
```

the `exists` array will contain ids and the status of each id that whether they exist in the mapping object or not